# pm2 serve build 80 --spa not working when I check pm2 status it says errored

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, pm2

i have hosted my websit on aws when running my react app on port 80
pm2 serve build 80 --spa
not working when I check pm2 status it says errored

it shoud be woring but showing error

please help me out from this.

2  │ static-page-server-80      │ default     │ 5.3.0   │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 30   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ ubuntu   │ disabled